# Subir archivos usando ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Hola que tal soy nueva en esto, estoy intentado subir 6 archivos al mismo tiempo desde un modal con un formulario usando ajax y que la dirección del archivo se guarde en una base de datos ejemplo: "Documentos/Archivo1.png", si lo logro hacer pero no siempre se suben los 6 archivos y no logro sacar la dirección para guardarla en una la base de datos, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Cuando intento subir los 6 archivos muchas veces solo suben 4 o 3 pero no me manda ninguno error, tampoco puedo definir que los tipos de archivos porque varían.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Código del modal que uso para los archivos:

```
<div id="modalNuevo" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Agrega nueva camiones</h4>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form name="enviarC" id="enviarC" enctype="multipart/from-data" method="post">
                        <label>Numero de camion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="numero_camion" class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Numero de seguro</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Verificacion</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Tenencia</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Referendo</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Permiso</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <label>Licencia</label>
                        <input type="file" name="archivo[]"  class="form-control input-sm">
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" name="insertar" id="insertar" value="Insertar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregarC();" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Función:

```
function agregarC() {
    var parametros = new FormData($("#enviarC")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/agregarDatos_camiones.php",
        data: parametros,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforesend: function() {
        }, success:function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Código para agregar los archivos:

```
$n=$_POST['numero_camion'];

$num_archivos=count($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
var_dump($num_archivos);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $num_archivos ; $i++) { 
    if (!empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i])) {
        $ruta_nueva = "Documentos/Camiones/" . $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i];
        $ruta_temporal=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($ruta_temporal, $ruta_nueva);
    }
}

$sql="INSERT into tabla_camiones (Numero_camion,Numero_seguro,Verificacion,Tenencia,Referendo,Permiso,Licencia) values ('$n','$num_archivos[0]','$num_archivos[1]','$num_archivos[2]','$num_archivos[3]','$num_archivos[4]','$num_archivos[5]')";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado el error.log? ¿no sale ningún error relacionado?

Answer (score 0):

que yo sepa no es posible con los lenguajes del lado del usuario por cuestiones de seguridad, puedes hacerlo con php que es un lenguaje del lado del servidor.

esto fue tomado de [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder leí el link que recomendaste había cosas que pase por alto pero, sigo en mi dilema. gracias.

Comment: Estas confundiendo la pregunta, con AJAX logras que el alta sea asíncrona procesando los datos del form con FormData por ejemplo y de ahí enviarlos al backend, dado eso no veo como este código que es muy similar al del OP le ayuda

Answer (score 0):

lo mas probable es un tema de tamaño y/o timeout. Revisa tu configuracion de php `upload_max_filesize`. Los errores los debe devolver en `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['error']`
puedes revisar el tamaño con un `if` tipo:

`if($_FILES['fichero_usuario']['error'] > $php_ini_maxsize) { ...`

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, no es el tamaño ni el tiempo lo acabo de checar y probé con  archivos de diferente tamaño y sigue asiendo lo mismo, sube los que quiere, también cambie la configuración a 20 mb y no pero gracias